# Push ViewController generates runtime exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, runtimeexception

I have a tabbed application. In the storyboard, one of the tabs is a navigation controller. On the root view, a UIImagePickerController pops up so that the user can take or select a photo.

```
/*SnapItViewController.m*/
#import "SnapItViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CollectionListViewController.h"
#import <sys/utsname.h>

@interface SnapItViewController ()

@end

@implementation SnapItViewController
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize currentLocation;

#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Listen to takePicture notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(TakePicture) name:@"takePicture" object:nil];
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }else{
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        //launch image picker view controller
        [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
#pragma mark - ImagePickerController Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage* theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if( picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);
    }
    int height = -1;
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"reduce_image"] == 0){
        height = 640;
    } else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"reduce_image"] == 1) {
        height = 1024;
    } else {
        height = 1600;
    }

    UIImage* resizedImageForUpload = [UtilityFunctions scaleAndRotateImage:theImage maxResolution:height];
    NSData* imageDataForUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImageForUpload, 1);   // reduced image! 

    NSString *userDataset = [UtilityFunctions retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"dataset"];

    [self didPickImage:imageDataForUpload atLocation:currentLocation
                     userDataset: userDataset];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];       
    [mLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];     
    [self release];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];      
}

- (void)pushChildControllerForCollectedLeaf:(CollectedLeaf*)theCollectedLeaf imageToUpload:(NSData*)imageToUpload animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CollectionDetailViewController* childController = [[[CollectionDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CollectionDetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    childController.collectedLeaf = theCollectedLeaf;

    //// Pass the image from image picker to Collection Detail View, and it'll handles the upload. ////
    //// Set to nil for existing collections. ////
    if (imageToUpload)
    {
        childController.imageToUpload = imageToUpload;
    }

    childController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:animated];
}

- (void)pushChildControllerForCollectedLeaf:(CollectedLeaf*)theCollectedLeaf imageToUpload:(NSData*)imageToUpload
{
    [self pushChildControllerForCollectedLeaf:theCollectedLeaf imageToUpload:imageToUpload animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Leaflet Photo Picker Delegate

- (void)didPickImage:(NSData*)imageData atLocation:(CLLocation*)cLocation userDataset:(NSString *)userDataset
{
    //// Creates a new Collected Leaf ////
    CollectedLeaf* collectedLeaf = (CollectedLeaf*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CollectedLeaf" inManagedObjectContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];

    //// Stores the geo-location to mCollectedLeaf ////
    if (cLocation)
    {
        collectedLeaf.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", cLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        collectedLeaf.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", cLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        collectedLeaf.altitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", cLocation.altitude];

    }
    else
    {
        collectedLeaf.latitude = kGeoLocationNotAvailable;
        collectedLeaf.longitude = kGeoLocationNotAvailable;
        collectedLeaf.altitude = kGeoLocationNotAvailable;
    }

    collectedLeaf.collectedDate = [NSDate date];
    collectedLeaf.selectedSpecies = kUnknownSpecies;
    collectedLeaf.userDataset = userDataset;

    [self pushChildControllerForCollectedLeaf:collectedLeaf imageToUpload:imageData animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Once the user selects a photo, it pushes the `CollectionDetailViewController` onto the nav stack. In the `viewDidLoad` method of `CollectionDetailViewController`, it pushes `CollectionDetailDataViewController` onto the nav stack, which displays a UITable.

```
/*CollectionDetailViewController.m */
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    containerView.frame = [self largeFrame];

    dataVC = [[CollectionDetailDataViewController alloc] init];
    dataVC.delegate = self;
    dataVC.collectedLeaf = self.collectedLeaf;
    dataVC.view.frame = [self normalFrame];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dataVC animated:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When I click on a cell of the UITable, it pushes a `SpeciesViewController` the app crashes with `Thread 1: exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    RankedSpecies *theRankedSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[[SpeciesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    speciesController.theSpecies = theRankedSpecies.Species;
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:speciesController animated:YES];

}
```

Thinking this was an issue of deallocation, I tried to comment out all dealloc methods involved but the issue persisted. I think replaced pushviewcontroller to adding `SpeciesViewController` as a subview of `CollectionDetailDataViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    RankedSpecies *theRankedSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SpeciesViewController* speciesController = [[[SpeciesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    speciesController.theSpecies = theRankedSpecies.Species;
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    [self addChildViewController:speciesController];
    [self.view addSubview:speciesController.view];
    [speciesController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

It now goes to the next view, but the app then crashes with the same exception code.

I have enabled Zombies and also added the exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator. I am working on getting a version of my code onto git so that others can experience my issue and potentially identify a solution.

the error printed in the consol:

```
2017-08-30 00:14:37.034 Leaflet-US[86918:4332982] *** -[SnapItViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fae4470d4c0
```

the crash stack trace:
[image]

Comment: autorelease? you are using ARC?

Comment: I inherited the app, so some of the code is old. I tried removing autorelease, but the issue persists

Comment: can you post all your crash log?

Comment: Of course - is the entire crash log the thread in the debug navigator xcode jumps to in the event of a crash?

Comment: Yes that is it, please copy and paste here to see what is wrong here

Comment: You must be on the main thread when Pushing Controller. You can be on any thread when using them, but loading them requires the main thread.

Comment: @VikasRajput Is that to say I have to be on the root view of the navigation controller to push a view controller?

Comment: if thats the case - then why was I able to push `CollectionDetailDataViewController` from `CollectionDetailViewController`?

Comment: Where is `SnapItViewController `? The crash is about it, but I cannot see the related code. By the way, you missed `[super viewDidLoad]` in the `viewDidLoad` method of `CollectionDetailViewController`

Comment: @AndyDarwin on the super viewDidLoad is there i just only posted code about pushing the view controller..I'll update that. And I will post code for SnapItViewController, good point!

Comment: @Matt we need the crash stack trace

Comment: @ReinierMelian did I update with the appropriate information?

Comment: @Matt yes that is it

Answer (score 0):

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[mLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[self release];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

You dismiss two viewControllers animately at the same time? Maybe you could try dismiss the second dismiss in the completion block. `self dismissViewControllerAnimated` is ambiguous, because it can dismiss the view controller on it or dismiss self. I think you want to dismiss self, that is `SnapItViewController`, so you release `SnapItViewController` first , then send a dismiss message to it, which is obviously wrong.

You post the `SnapItViewController` code, but still, you did not post where you call it.

Comment: SnapItViewController is the rootview controller on the "Snap It" tab - I did not write code for it to be called, StoryBoard sets it up for me

Comment: I dismiss the UIImagePickerViewController then I dismiss SnapItViewController, then in didPickImage, I push a new view, which definitely is not thought out well. But If I remove the second dismiss, my program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being removing

```
[self release]

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` in SnapItViewController.

Comment: I can't recall EVER seeing release called on self...that just seems like a really bad idea to me in general.  Is there a valid use case for doing that?

Comment: Also, assuming you are using ARC, you should rarely need to call release anyway.